# A new Lie group associated to a given Lie group

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups

**Edit:** According to the comment of Ycor we remove the phrase "Naturally arises from a left invariant metric'

Let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. We fix an orientation for $G$. We denote by $H$ the group of all orientation preserving diffeomorphisms $f$ of $G$ such that for every $X\in \mathfrak{g}$ we have $f^* X$ belong to $\mathfrak{g}$.

Is there a natural Lie group structure for $H$ which contains $G$ as a closed normal subgroup? How can the constant curvature of $H$ and also its Lie algebra be related to those objects for $G$?

As a simplest example we get the group of affine linear maps $x\mapsto ax+b,\quad a>0$ of the real line when $G=\mathbb{R}$, a model of Poincare upper plane.

Comment: I assume you are including $\mathfrak{g}$ into vector fields on $G$ by taking the left-invariant extension?

Comment: Isn't $H$ just the orientation-preserving subgroup of $Aut_{Lie}(G)$?

Comment: The second sentence has two verbs so should be syntactically fixed. It also suggest that a Riemannian metric induces an orientation, which is false.

Comment: @user44191 is right, and the argument is purely abstract: in a group $G$, denoting by $G_{\mathrm{left}}$ the subgroup of the group $S(G)$ of permutations of $G$ consisting of left translations, then its normalizer in $S(G)$ is the semidirect product $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\ltimes G_{\mathrm{left}}$ (exercise). Restricting to the subgroup of orientation-preserving diffeomorphisms gives the conclusion.

Comment: @YCor It is  realy true that every Riemannian metric gives an orientation. If $g_{ij}$ be the tensor metric then $\sqrt{det (g_{ij})} dx_1\wedge \ldots\wedge dx_n$ is the volum form associated to our metric. It is independent of coordinate chart. So this volum form determine a unique orientation.

Comment: @AliTaghavi It isn't. Every manifold admits a Riemannian metric, including non-orientable ones... also the isometry group of many Riemannian manifolds, including positive-dimensional Euclidean spaces, does not preserve the orientation. Your argument fails because you're just working in a chart and using the orientation of the chart.

Comment: @YCor  Yes you are right I should write " we fix an orientation for G since it is orientable.

Comment: @user44191  What is the definition of $Aut_{Lie }G$?

Comment: It's the group of differentiable group automorphisms. Which turns out to also be the group of continuous automorphisms.

Comment: @YCor  (and even analytic, i think) But I do not see why? Even translations( which belongs to H, they are not group homomorphism)  i really do not understand why the H I described has two  interpretations described by you and user44191

Comment: @YCor  BTW after we fix an orientable atlas, the volum form i mentioned does not depend on chart.

Comment: @YCor I think my answer is incorrect (as shown by the example in the OP), though I was aiming at the "purely abstract" method you have. I should have said that the subgroup of $H$ that fixes the identity is the orientation-preserving subgroup $Aut^+(G)$, which leads to an answer of $Aut^+(G) \ltimes G_{left}$, if I'm not mistaken again.

Comment: @user44191 Sorry if my question is elementary  Let $f$ fix the identity. Why it must be a  group homomorphism?9Not that $f$ is assumed to be a diffeomorphism whose action keep invariant the lie algebra of left invariant vector field)

Comment: A quick argument that I haven't checked explicitly: $[a, b] = \lim_{s, t \rightarrow 0} \text{exp}(sa) \text{exp}(tb) \text{exp}(-sa) \text{exp}(-tb)$; as $f$ preserves left-invariant vector fields, it preserves the entire right-hand side of the equation, so $df([a, b]) = [df(a), df(b)]$, so $df$ is an automorphism of $\mathfrak{g}$, which implies that $f$ must be an automorphism on $G_0$. $f$ doesn't have to be a group automorphism otherwise (e.g. take $G$ discrete), so I was still slightly wrong above, but if $G$ is connected, I should be right.

Comment: @user44191  that f preserves the space $\mathcal{g}$ of  left invariant vector fields  does not mean that $f^* X=X\quad \forall  X \in \mathfrak{g}$. Did not you used the later in your comment?

Comment: @user44191  moreover is the equality you wrote correct?

Comment: The right side (befor we take limit) are member of G.

Comment: The equation is incorrect (I forgot to un-exponentiate and divide), but can be corrected: $[a, b] = \lim_{s, t \rightarrow 0} \frac{exp^{-1}(\text{exp(sa)} exp(tb) exp(-sa) exp(-tb))}{st}$, where we take $s, t$ small enough for the exponential map to be bijective. The idea is that multiplying on the left by $exp(sa)$ (and each of the others) should be equivalent to following the left-invariant vector field, and therefore $f$ should pass through the exponentiations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98566/discussion-between-user44191-and-ali-taghavi).

Comment: @user44191  i  sincerely thank you very much for your very intriguing beautiful  and clear answer in the chat discussion. now i completely understand.

Comment: @YCor Thank you very much  Yves for your attention to my question and your very interesting comments. I try to understand its details.